# CountIfs for Date Range returning 0 for dates higher than

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search a column for matches for

1. cause,
2. greater than MinDate and
3. less than MaxDate.

For some reason the less than MaxDate is returning zero, I suspect it might be due to Date conversion but cannot find the root of the problem.

I tried splitting the CountIfs into 2 CountIf and doing a subtraction but still get errors with the Max Date.
If I try certain dates I get some values but they seem inaccurate, this eliminates the date calculator code.

```
Q = MA.Range("H2").Value
Y = MA.Range("H3").Value
S = 1
If Q = 1 Or Q = 4 Then
    E = 31
Else
    E = 30
End If

MinDate = DateSerial(2016 + Y, (1 + ((Q - 1) * 3)), 1)
MaxDate = DateSerial(2016 + Y, (Q * 3), 30)

MA.Range("E21").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(AC.Range("R1:R9999"), "=" & OP.Range("A21"), AC.Range("L1:L9999"), ">=" & MinDate, AC.Range("L1:L9999"), "<=" & MaxDate)
```

Comment: Can you give a single example of a date which should pass the "maxdate" test but does not?

Comment: Sure, if I am searching within quarter 4:
MinDate = 1/7/2018
MaxDate =30/9/2018, 
for a Cause = Planning, there is a match on 6/7/2018 but with the above code a zero is returned, if I use reduce it to just search greater than the MinDate it is counted as well as those past my set MaxDate

Comment: Are you sure `6/7/2018` in your spreadsheet is formatted `DD/MM/YYYY` and not `MM/DD/YYYY`?

Comment: Does your formula return expected results if you enter it directly (manually) onto the worksheet?

Comment: What's your default date format?  mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: The spreadsheet and column are most definitely set to dd/mm/yyyy, and I believe so is the serial as it prints out such in a MsgBox. If I replace MinDate and MaxDate with direct date entries I still get a zero return.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out, there is a numerical conversion of Dates in Excel which is calculated by American standard date format, despite the data being inputted and outputted in dd/mm/yyyy, ie numbers of days since 1/1/1900 as an integer. As this numerical value is used in the workings it causes incorrect outputs. For anyone interested to get around this I have used these additions:
`AC.Range("L1:L9999"), ">=" & CDbl(CDate(MinDate)), AC.Range("L1:L9999"), "<=" & CDbl(CDate(MaxDate))`. 
Thanks to those who offered help.